# mysql select inner join with limit

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have 2 tables, category and articles, I want to get 5 articles for each category, the tables look like this:

```
category: id, name
articles: id, title, body, category_id
```

So what I normally do is INNER JOIN, but I get all rows, how can I specify that I need only 5 rows per category, I imagine it would need a SELECT within a SELECT ?

Comment: What criteria are you using for your "top 5"?

Comment: @JeffWatkins I have articles date and ORDER BY date DESC but really that's not important for now, thx though

Comment: Check: [Within-group quotas (Top N per group)](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=104)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a rank query mysql does not have window functions for this type of results to get n records per group,i will not suggest a `group_concat` solution because as `articles`  terms says that there can be enough data and easily by pass the 1024 character limit constraint if you increase this limit it also has a dependency on [*`max_allowed_packet`*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) too

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT *,
@r:= CASE WHEN @g = c.id THEN @r +1 ELSE 1 END rownum,
@g:= c.id catgroup
 FROM category c
 JOIN articles a ON (c.id = a,category_id)
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @g:=0,@r:=0) t2
ORDER BY c.id , a.`date` desc
) t
 WHERE rownum <= 5
```

Above will rank each article within in its category group you can see the result of `rownum` alias and in outer query just filter the results of articles to 5 per category group

Comment: This code does work. But how do I limit to search only for categories within limit not all of them?. Like if we have 100 categories but we want to show articles only for first 10 (Limit 0,10) then next 10 (Limit 10,20) etc ? I tried putiing LIMIT with your code but doesnt seem to work it returns all the categories. I want the inner Join to be performed on a section of categories data

Comment: @voytez you can ask a new question for your problem a little for your problem will be in from clause use a sub select instead of category table like `from (select * from category order by some_col limit 0,10) as c`

Comment: Many thanks! now it works with pagination. I didn't ask a new question since this is regarding your answer but adding the select from * order by date limit $start, $end instead of FROM category C helped :)

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid unfortnately it doesnt seem to work properly when adding more than 3 comments, can you have a look at my detailed reply below? Maybe im doing something wrong as rownum seems to count only up to 3. Added new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35115793/mysql-inner-join-limiting-results

Answer (score 1):

You can hack your query using `group_concat` in MySQL since MySQL does not support windows functions unfortunately. It won't look pretty though.

You can use [this blog post](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/selecting-a-specific-non-aggregated-column-data-in-group-by) as inspiration to build the query you need.

Other possibility is to retrieve every article in category and filter the top 5 yourself at the client side (PHP, Java, Python, you name it).

Comment: thanks @Pablo, I thought there could be an easier way than doing it from the client side, but I guess there is no running away from it!