# mysql inner join limiting results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, spots and comments(for locations), comments are referencing spots by a column spot_id and i want to pick last 3 comments per every spot I have in spots db.

I'm using the code from by M Khalid Junaid in this question: [mysql select inner join limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25592126/mysql-select-inner-join-with-limit)

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT c.id, a.author_id, a.author_username, a.comment, a.timestamp,
@r:= CASE WHEN @g = c.id THEN @r +1 ELSE 1 END rownum,
@g:= c.id catgroup
 FROM (SELECT * FROM spots ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT $start_index , $rows_count) as c
 JOIN comments a ON (c.id = a.spot_id)
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @g:=0,@r:=0) t2
ORDER BY c.id , a.timestamp desc
) t
 WHERE rownum <= 3
```

But the problem is it returns more than 3 rows as rownum after hitting three stats counting from 1.

This is result for rownum <= 3

[image]

As you can see i get 5 comments for spot id 58 instead of just 3. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not assign variables in one expression and then use them in another.  MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in a `select` statement.  In your case, this applies to `@g`.

So, the right way to write the query is to do the variable manipulation in a single expression:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *,
             (@r := IF(@g = c.id, @r + 1,
                       IF(@g := c.id, 1, 1)
                      )
             ) as rownum,
             c.id as catgroup
      FROM category c JOIN
           articles a
           ON c.id = a.category_id CROSS JOIN 
           (SELECT @g := 0, @r := 0) params
      ORDER BY c.id, a.`date` desc
     ) t
WHERE rownum <= 5;
```

Of course, if you only want three results, then change the "5" to a "3".

Comment: thanks for reply but unfortunately doesnt seem to work, produces exactly the same result...i get all 5 comments back even tho rownum is <= 3. All rownums reset to 1 after reaching three and therefore are included in results

Comment: so the problem depends on the order of adding comments, if the reference spot_id is not added in ascending order the above query wont work, if i add commens with spot ids 1111222333(every number is a row referencing to id of spo) it works but in my case ids wont be added in asc order and might be mixed like 11211333232

Comment: You should be getting 3/5 rows back for each `c.id`.

Comment: So I found out that this wasn't working as my comments (or articles) table was ordered by its unique primary key id which was causing trouble with that solution. Once I changed my comments table to be ordered by timestamp (in PhpMyAdmin table options) it worked...i found that different table order (by uid or spot_id or timestamp) they all have impact on the result of the query and found the last one to be correct, not really sure why though...)